# Enable Angular CLI in WebStorm

Tags: angular, webstorm, angular-cli

I have an existing project for which I want to enable *Angular CLI* in *WebStorm*. I have successfully used the CLI functionality in WebStorm in 'pure' Angular CLI projects.

I've made sure that the NodeJS and AngularJS plugins are enabled in WebStorm.

If I run `ng version` in the project I get:

```
@angular/cli: 1.0.0-rc.1
node: 6.10.0
os: darwin x64
@angular/common: 2.4.6
@angular/compiler: 2.4.6
@angular/core: 2.4.6
@angular/forms: 2.4.6
@angular/http: 2.4.6
@angular/platform-browser: 2.4.6
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 2.4.6
@angular/router: 3.4.6
@angular/cli: 1.0.0-rc.1
@angular/compiler-cli: 2.4.6
@angular/platform-server: 2.4.6
@angular/tsc-wrapped: 0.3.0
```

And the contents of my 'manually created' `.angular-cli.json` is:

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "project": {
    "name": "blaha-client"
  },
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src/client"
    }
  ],
  "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "scss"
  }
}
```

The CLI works from the terminal prompt but the wizard functionality in WebStorm cannot be found under 'right-click->new'. From the actions menu I can search the Angular CLI but when I click in nothing happens.

Anybody knows what I am missing?

EDIT: I do not wish to convert the project to a cli project entirely, only to be able to use the wizard-like functionality in WebStorm.

EDIT: Note that as of 2019, 'angular-cli.json' has been renamed 'angular.json'

Comment: Accordingly to [this message](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/205452350/comments/204881650) it is enough to have `angular-cli.json` **in the project root**. I've just tested this in PhpStorm 2016.3.2 with that file completely **empty** and Angular CLI options are there. What the IDE version BTW?

Comment: I've got WebStorm 2016.3.3. I've noticed that projects created with `angular-cli-1.0.0-beta24` creates a `angular-cli.json` but the ones I create with `angular-cli-1.0.0-rc1` creates a `.angular-cli.json` probably throwing WebStorm of.

Comment: Try 2017.1 EAP build it should support new file name `.angular-cli.json` already (not checked myself though).

Comment: Thanks, that did it.

Comment: For Angular6 this file is now angular.json. And instead of  `(right-click) -> new ->Angular cli...` it's now `(right-click) -> new ->Angular Schematic...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Accordingly to [this message](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/205452350/comments/204881650) it is enough to have `angular-cli.json` **in the project root**. I've just tested this in PhpStorm 2016.3.2 with that file being completely empty and Angular CLI options are there in `File | New...` menu.

For `.angular-cli.json` support (the same file but with leading dot -- as of [1.0.0-rc.0](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-rc.0-update#angular-clijson)) -- try [2017.1 EAP build](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/WI/WebStorm+EAP) -- it should support new file name already.

Answer (score 1):

Note that as of 2019, 'angular-cli.json' has been renamed 'angular.json'